# Spring Boot integration test fails if @Transactional

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-boot-test, spring-data-jdbc

I have a simple Spring Boot application using Spring Data JDBC repositories and exposing REST API. Everything seems to be running OK except for my integration tests. See below an excerpt from repository configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcRepositories
class RepositoryConfig : AbstractJdbcConfiguration() {

    @Bean
    @Profile("int-test")
    fun intTestDataSource(): DataSource {
        return EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("sql/h2/schema_create.sql")
                .build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun namedParameterJdbcOperations(dataSource: DataSource): NamedParameterJdbcOperations {
        return NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource)
    }

    @Bean
    fun transactionManager(dataSource: DataSource): TransactionManager {
        return DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource)
    }
}
```

The integration test follows.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("int-test")
@Transactional
class OrganizationControllerIntTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var organizationRepository: OrganizationRepository

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var restTemplate: TestRestTemplate

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var testDataGenerator: TestDataGenerator

    @BeforeEach
    fun beforeEach() {
        val organizations = testDataGenerator.organizations(10).toList()
        organizationRepository.saveAll(organizations)
    }

    @Test
    fun `When GET organizations then return all organizations`() {
        val result = restTemplate.getForEntity("/organizations", String::class.java)
        assertThat(result?.statusCode, equalTo(HttpStatus.OK))
        assertThat(result?.body, containsString("items"))
    }
}
```

The test is successful if `@Transactional` annotation is not applied. Since I need the changes to be rollbacked after each test, I would like to make the tests transactional. The problem is that in that case the response does not contain any items like the database would be empty and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: If your test is transactional nothing is being committed and rolled back after the test. However it is only visible inside the transaction. As you are calling an actual endpoint that doesn't see the data simply  because it isn't committed yet. Using `@Transactional` with a full blown integration test won't work (it will work when using `MockMvc` because that doesn't issue an actual request and runs in the same thread and transaction.

Comment: It does make sense. What is the usual practice to reset the database state after/before each integration test then? Just deleting everything in `@AfterEach` method? Would you consider converting your comment into an answer so that I can accept it and make it available for others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `@Transactional` with a system test won't work.

What happens is the data in your `@BeforeEach` method is inserted into the database **but** the transaction never commits. The data is only visible inside the same transaction.

Now you send a HTTP request to the server which opens a new connection to the database and starts a new transaction. However as the data from the other transaction isn't committed it won't see anything.

The `@Transactionl` will only work when using `MockMvc` as that will run inside the same transaction and thread. With an actual HTTP request being made that isn't the case.

To use data setup for each test, although you should be cautious with this when doing a full system test! you either:

1. Write your test in such a way that it doesn't matter, if you really want a system test.
2. use `MockMvc` to run your test, instead of an actual HTTP request which will make it (re)use the same transaction.
3. Don't write a system test but use `@WebMvcTest` to test your controller